# How to register multiple member in one civicrm membership sign up form?

Tags: 7, civicrm

I have a special promotion price set for member: Register 1 new member is USD 500, register 2 new members in one-time is USD 800.

In my membership sign up form (created using contribution page), I would like the user to enter 2 member details during sign up.

I found this function in event page, where user can register multiple participants in one event, and make payment. But, the payment can't extend the membership period and can't create new membership.

I tried to adjust my price set setting by changing "used for" option, but it shows error of "If you plan on using this price set for membership signup and renewal, you can not also use it for Events or Contribution."

By selecting it using for membership, I can choose the price option to have different number of terms. But, this can't be used in event page which allow multiple registration of participant / member.

Is there any way I can register multiple member in one membership sign up form?

Comment: If you haven't already done so, it would be great to see you supporting the proposal for the new CiviCRM StackExchange site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm?referrer=sZxmfwEWAHDXeNHrjdyxXQ2

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do this directly within CiviCRM via the user interface. I get around this problem by using the webform (https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) and webform_civicrm (https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm) modules. Using this you have a far more flexible approach, and can produce a sign-up form that can create memberships for multiple contacts.

I've never understood why CiviCRM, which has a membership management as a core function, does not provide this functionality itself.

Comment: Of course, forgot to mention that the webform based approach has its own constraints. It doesn't work with price sets and memberships are always sold at the minimum price that is set in the membership type configuration. Trying to sell more than one membership at a time is difficult.

Comment: Webform works for multiple contact registration! But now I'm facing the problem of payment, where the payment processor included in my contribution page is paypal, and in webform, the payment processor shows only "Pay later"... Is there any method I can let them pay before the form submission updates the membership?

Comment: Paypal Standard does not currently work with webform_civicrm, but work is underway to change that. I've got Stripe working, if that's an option for you?

Comment: Agreed that webform_civicrm is the way to go, and that it doesn't work with "off-site" processors at the moment.